# How to get all the element from HTML who having same class attribute?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I developing one asp.net application in that I using htmlagility dll to get all `<div>` tags which is same class attributes..

How to get all elements who have same class from whole html page,

 I getting top 1 div who having class='myclass' but in, 
 
 my case I want to all div tags who have 'myclass' class.

```
var vardoc = web.Load("<any website url>"); 
var varmyclass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='myclass']");
```

when I used above method then I getting inner html content of the 'myclass' but in my html contents there are many div tags who have class 'myclass'.
I want to get all `<div>` who have same class using HTMLagility or other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select a single node in that case.

You are using `SelectSingleNode`, which will return only one node.

Use `SelectNodes` instead:

```
var varmyclass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='myclass']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much searching an XML document for these nodes.

First off, you're selecting a single node which will only return 1. You need to use SelectNodes.

example:

```
var varmyclass = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='myclass']");
```

Update - Removed my Xpath suggestion as it didn't work as I thought it would...

Answer (score 0):

Two issues, first one is that you should be using `SelectNodes()` instead as the other answers have pointed out since you want to select multiple nodes.

Also, your XPath is a bit restrictive.  It will only get `div` elements which has only one class, `myclass` but doesn't include those that have multiple classes.  I suspect you want to include those as well.  Rather than checking if the class is equal, check if it contains it.

```
var xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'myclass')]";
var query = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```